# querying fields with name containing whitespace using OData

Tags: odata

I have to make a $filter query on a field that's name contains whitespace. 
Eg, 
$filter=Ticket No eg 'abc_123'

I'm starting to think its not possible. Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thought I'd share this, I was trying to query rest services through my SharePoint hosted SharePoint 2013 app and well I found the solution. All you need to do is replace the spaces in the field name by `_x0020_`

Comment: that would be like "Ticket_x0020_No"

Comment: This is perfect! I was looking to add special characters to Excel column headings and this worked like a charm. If setting up an OData feed using WCF Data services and you need spaces, this works when you add it to the property name of your POCO.

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers, replace spaces with "_x0020_" not "x0020"

Comment: I just realized that stackoverflow uses underscores to italicize words.  My comment above should state that the format is underscore x00200 underscore.

Answer (score 2):

OData property names cannot contain spaces. Refer to the xsd schema [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/cs01/schemas/edm.xsd). Look for the type TSimpleIdentifier in the schema. The definition looks like the following,

```
<xs:simpleType name="TSimpleIdentifier">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="128" />
        <!-- ECMAScript identifiers not starting with a '$' -->
        <xs:pattern value="[\p{L}\p{Nl}_][\p{L}\p{Nl}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Pc}\p{Cf}]{0,}" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```